# Why Zend_View_Helper_Url returns relative path when using the default route and absolute path when using a custom route?

Tags: zend-framework, url, zend-route, view-helpers

I have an application running on Zend Framework 1.12 and I am using the URL view helper. I also have a few custom routes which I use with the URL helper to clean the code.

When I use a format such as this:

```
$this->url(array('module' => 'myapp', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'), 'default', true)
```

The resulting string is a relative path to the action - `/myapp/index/index`

But when I use a custom route as such:

```
$this->url(array('var' => 'value'), 'custom-route', true)
```

The resulting string is an absolute path - `http://www.domain.com/custom-route`

I don't understand why is this happening and I can't find any information about this behavior  online. Furthermore, I wish to know if there's a way to prevent it from happening and produce consistency in the way the URL view helper works (preferably to always return a relative path).

Thanks.

Comment: Is custom-route a hostname route? If not I'm not sure how this would happen

Comment: It's a regular route for all I know. `Zend_Controller_Router_Route`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is as simple as your first example being a default type  `Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module` route that is normally relative.

Your second example is a *named* route so it needs to include the base url in order to be valid. I don't believe rewritten routes can be relative as the route may or may not refer to an actual location.

I've done some limited testing and I believe that if you set your *baseUrl* value the first example will also include the host address. So for consistency your urls will always be absolute.

```
//application.ini
resources.frontController.baseurl = http://www.domain.com
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In the route definition I only provide module, controller, action and custom parameters (if I have any), no domain of any kind. I see no reason why the URL should not be relative. I still hope there's a way to make the both relative instead of absolute.

Comment: check out the `assemble()` method in `Zend_Controller_Router_Route`, `Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite` and `Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module` to see how the different routes are put together. Only your first example is of the `module` type.